# Java: How can I send message to all channels from NIO Server

Tags: java, client-server, nio, socketchannel

Is there any functionality provided by NIO package for sending messages to all active ClientChannels?

I can just loop through all the keys anytime I am reading from some Channel, like it is done [here](https://gist.github.com/Botffy/3860641), but I am interested in using specifically NIO functionality (registering channels with OP_WRITE etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Java NIO channels are a thin wrapper around OS sockets.

Just like there is no way to send one packet to multiple sockets, there is no way to send one message to multiple channels in a single call.

You might want to look into [IP multicasting](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/introduction-multicasting/) using [MulticastSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html), but it requires the network to support it.